# Boot a clean Windows image on disk at every restart without CD/DVD/USB

Tags: backup, disk-image

I am confused behind all the jargon with disk imaging and cloning.

I plan to make 2 partitions. 1 for data and 1 for Windows Software.

And I just want to start a "clean/checkpointed" Windows 10 every time the computer restarts, transparently (without user intervention). I don't want to use the CD.

Is CloneZilla enough for this? Should I use [Volume Shadow Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Copy)?
Should I try something else? I prefer Open Source Software.

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "clean"?  An image that saves no changes made, and upon reboot, boots in the same state it was at last boot (similar to PCs in libraries, schools, Best Buy/other stores, etc)?  If so, WIMboot could be utilized.  VSS is the underlying service that handles checkpoint creation/system restore.

As to imaging, Windows has always included native tools to image a partition with... see [this](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/43532/32695) post.